# Ошибка при компиляции программы в CodeLite

Tags: codelite

Мне никак не удаётся нормально подключить к своему проекту нужную библиотеку (речь идёт о console.h и console.lib, в качестве среды использую CodeLite).

В настройках проекта я указал пути до этих двух библиотек (в разделах Compiler и Linker), но при компиляции простой программы, использующей функции данной библиотеки, появляется следующая ошибка (смотрите скриншот).

Скажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так, и как мне это исправить? 
Буду благодарен за развёрнутый ответ, чтобы в дальнейшем не испытывать проблем подобного рода.

[image: ошибка]

Comment: Явно написано, какой файл не найден.

Comment: Файл console.lib находится в указанной директории, но почему-то он cannot find(

Comment: А откуда вы его брали?

Comment: Скачал с сайта, посвящённому написанию игр типа roguelike.

Comment: А тожет быть lib несовместимого с вашими тулзами формата